# How to connect another server using network?

Tags: c#, web-services

I want to connect to another server using network.
So I write below code.

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"10.3.4.56");

            using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
```

But there is error and it says

```
Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Try `var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"http://10.3.4.56/");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you pass in to `WebRequest.Create` needs to be a valid [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx). Try `WebRequest.Create("http://10.3.4.56")`.

**TIP!** Use the static `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` method to check if the URI string is valid.

Answer (score 1):

try including the shema
    "http://10.3.4.56"